# Problem invoking azurerm_api_management_api_operation with URI parameters

Tags: terraform, azure-api-management, terraform-provider-azure

i am trying to import an API operation (with Swagger JSON spec). However, its complaining of my URI parameter. I am a bit at loss as what its complaining about.

Here is my Terraform snippet with the swagger/Open API spec:

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "sample_api_v2" {
  name                = "sample-api-v2"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg_name
  api_management_name = module.abc01.name
  revision            = "1"
  display_name        = "Sample Data API v2"
  path                = "Sample-data/v2"
  protocols           = ["https"]
  version             = "v2"
  version_set_id      = azurerm_api_management_api_version_set.sample-api-version-set.id
  import {
    content_format = "openapi+json"
    content_value  = <<JSON
    {
    "openapi": "3.0.1",
    "info": {
        "title": "Sample API v2",
        "description": "Sample Data API v2",
        "contact": {
        "name": "John Smith",
        "email": "john.smith@email.com"
        },
        "version": "v2"
    },
    "servers": [
        {
        "url": "https://my-api.example.com/sample-api/v2"
        }
    ],
    "paths": {
        "/businesses/{abn}": {
        "get": {
            "summary": "Get Businesses",
            "description": "Retrieve the abn information of the business with the matching abn number",
            "operationId": "get-business-by-abn",
            "parameters": [
            {
                "name": "abn",
                "in": "path",
                "required": true,
                "schema": {
                "type": "number"
                }
            }
            ],
            "responses": {
            "200": {
                "description": "ABN Found"
            }
            }
        }
        }
    },
    "components": {
        "securitySchemes": {
        "apiKeyQuery": {
            "type": "apiKey",
            "name": "subscription-key",
            "in": "query"
        }
        }
    },
    "security": [
        {
        "apiKeyQuery": []
        }
    ]
    }
    JSON
  }
}
```

The `azurerm_api_management_api_operation` block is defined as:

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation" "get_business_by_abn_v2" {
  operation_id        = "get-business-by-abn"
  api_name            = azurerm_api_management_api.sample_api_v2.name
  api_management_name = module.abc01.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg_name
  display_name        = "Lookup business by ABN"
  method              = "GET"
  url_template        = "/businesses/{abn}"
  description         = "Lookup a business by ABN Number"
  response {
    status_code = 200
  }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
: apimanagement.APIOperationClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="ValidationError" Message="One or more fields contain incorrect values:" Details=[{"code":"ValidationError","message":"All template parameters used in the UriTemplate must be defined in the Operation, and vice-versa.","target":"templateParameters"}]
```

I have done the following:

1. I have validated the Spec in Swagger online editor
2. The parameters block is clearly defined to match the path:

```
{
   "name": "abn",
   "in": "path",
   "required": true,
   "schema": {
   "type": "number"
   }
}
```

I am finding this is only happening with URI params. For my other APIs with query parameters this problem doesn't happen.

Can anyone please suggest what might be going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears with URI params you must specify it in the Terraform as well:

Refer to the `template_parameter` block below:

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation" "get_business_by_abn_v2" {
  operation_id        = "get-business-by-abn"
  api_name            = azurerm_api_management_api.sample_api_v2.name
  api_management_name = module.abc01.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg_name
  display_name        = "Lookup business by ABN"
  method              = "GET"
  url_template        = "/businesses/{abn}"
  description         = "Lookup a business by ABN Number"
  
  template_parameter {
    name    = "abn"
    type    = "number"
    required = true
  }
  
  response {
    status_code = 200
  }
}
```

In my trial & error, it doesnt care if query params dont get specified. But URI params must be specified in both Open API specification and the Terraform resource via `template_parameter` section.